# Differences in notation of momentum 4 vector

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, units, conventions, dimensional-analysis

I have noticed three ways to write the 4 momentum vectors:

1. $P = (E/c, \vec{p})$
2. $P = (E, \vec{p})$
3. $P = (E, c\vec{p})$

I know how to derive equation 1, and as far as I know, one can use the equation 2 to make problem solving less troublesome by putting $c = 1$ m/s. However, equation 3 does not make any sense to me, because the LHS does not contain $cP$ but only $P$, so I don't really understand this way to write the momentum 4-vector at all. How is it possible to write like this?

Comment: Where did you see that last one

Comment: @TylerHG: my physics homework, it is stated that I should use equation 3 above to solve a comptom scattering problem

Comment: (3) has units of energy for all four elements, while (1) has units of momentum for all four, leading to consistency of units which is convenient for Special Relativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use equation 3 as a definition. Yes, its dimension will differ from that of momentum, but this is not a big deal. That would not be a worse 4-vector than that of equation 1 - they differ just by a constant factor. And to use equation 2 you use a system of units where c=1, not 1 m/s.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) Could you also please tell why equation 3 is better to use for solving a problem than equation 1? I just can't understand why one can't just stick to either equation 1 or equation 2 since equation 3 has a dimension different from momentum anyway (this way of thinking is a little bit tricky for me because I've always learned to check that the dimensions in my calculations are correct)

Comment: @Phillip A: As I said, I don't see much difference between 1 and 3, so I am not sure there is some deep reason why 3 is better than 1 or vice versa. As for checking dimensions, that is certainly a good habit, but choosing 3 does not mean there will be any problems with dimensions. The only (minor) problem is that we call it "momentum", but it has a different dimension than the momentum we are used to. However, special relativity suggests that energy and momentum should have the same dimension anyway:-)